# Error (invalid 'row.names' length) when using cohen.d function from effsize package

Tags: r, statistics

I have a sample dataframe called (df1) that look like this:

| Score | Condition |
| --- | --- |
| 23 | 1 |
| 64 | 1 |
| 43 | 1 |
| 19 | 1 |
| 25 | 1 |

And a separate dataframe (called df2) that looks like this:

| Score | Condition |
| --- | --- |
| 98 | 2 |
| 86 | 2 |
| 78 | 2 |
| 79 | 2 |
| 69 | 2 |

While I can easily run a Welch independent samples t-test with the following code:

```
t.test(df1$Score, df2$Score)
```

I have trouble obtaining the Cohen's d for my Welch t statistic using the `effsize` package. Specifically, using the following code:

```
cohen.d(df1$Score,df2$Score)
```

I often get the following error:

```
Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : invalid 'row.names' length
```

Strangely, sometimes, the code works and I get both Cohen's d and the 95% CI as output. This occurred twice. Once when I updated the effsize package (it is now updated to version 0.8.1 but the same error still occurs after I restart R) and again when I was trying other packages (e.g. lyr) to obtain Cohen's d, gave up and tried running the same code again.

I have double checked and ensured my Score column is numeric.

May I know what did I do wrong?

Thank you :)

Comment: When the length of x is not equal to the length of values, this error is thrown. Could it be your data frames are not of similar length? Is there missing data present that messes with the function outputs?
For example, when using `value = 15`,  and `x = c(10,10)`, `.rowNamesDF<-(x, value = value)` throws the error.

Comment: Hi Knalwous, thank you for your comment. The data was all collected by me personally so I am very certain that there are no missing data in my dataframe. Just in case, I ran the essential tests and they all turned out fine.